# How does the Kubernetes load balancer service interact with the AWS / GKE load balancer?

Tags: kubernetes

How exactly does a 'Load Balancer' get provisioned on a cloud provider like AWS / GCP when creating a Kubernetes `service` with a type of `LoadBalancer`?

Which component is actually responsible for interacting with the cloud provider's API? Or is this something that occurs internally on the cloud provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier it was kube-controller-manager but now it is https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/running-cloud-controller/

The cloud controller manager has been taken out of the kube-controller-manager post v1.6.

> As of 1.8, it has a service controller which is responsible for
>   loadbalancers on the cloud against services of type LoadBalancer.